# How to position a div right at the bottom of a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I would like to position a div at the right edge bottom of a table. I am using bootstrap and I found out using offest I can move the div right at the bottom corner of the table but I did not like this solution as seems not to work correctly. So how can I position a div right at the bottom corner of a table that is inside a modal. the following block is the one that I am trying to position right bottom of the table:

```
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 col-sm-offset-9 col-xs-offset6">
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id=""></label>
                                <label id=""></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id=""></label>
                                <label id=""></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id=""></label>
                                <label id=""></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Full code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="panel panel-primary panel-primary-trim">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body panel-body-trim">
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table id="items-job-payments-modal-table" class="table table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Date</th>
                                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>DateExample</td>
                                                            <td>10</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10 col-sm-offset-9 col-xs-offset6">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                        <label id=""></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>                               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The div will hold some information such as remaining balance so I want it to be at the edge or the right bottom of the table

Comment: can you simplify your code to just what's needed? you probably don't need all those Bootstrap classes at the very least!

Comment: What do you need me to simplify? the code basically includes a modal inside a modal there is a table that takes 10 columns and a div section that holds three labels that takes 2 columns. I am trying to display the div with labels next to the table at the right bottom. I did try use offest to move the div around but I would like to know the proper way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

I would place the table into an `inline-block` div (wrapper) that has relative positioning, then use absolute positioning (`bottom: 0, right: 0`) for the element you want at the bottom right.  The table and the positioned element are both children of the relative positioned wrapper.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 3rem;
  background: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
.bottomRight {
  position: relative;
  background: #bbb;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <table>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="bottomRight">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like the div to be at the right bottom of edge of the table its going to be a separate section that holds total price and balance would your solution works on mobile view @robertwade

Comment: @RoberWade I am trying to do a separate section another div that holds total price and balanace like a box next to the table your solution content overlaps on smaller secreen size

Comment: @user16908948 Sorry instructions unclear. Thought you wanted the new box positioned *over* the bottom right.  I've updated the snippet above in my original answer to place it *next* to the table at bottom right.  This version will simply use flex box positioning to place the items rather than absolute positioning.